# Efficient Way to Scale PHP/AJAX Polling a Website for Changes

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

We're creating a PHP-based website with a MySQL database. Presenter is showing a web site on a projector. The website has presentation images and text and a poll area.

Audience with mobile devices can log into a site that shows that current poll question, and allows the audience to in near realtime to vote in the poll.

AJAX is running in a loop hitting a PHP script, querying a database in order to generate near real-time results on the presentation screen.

I am hoping there is some way to use an event listener of sorts in order to receive notification that something has changed instead of constantly pinging the server.

Unfortunately, we don't have a public view of the site that I can post here, but wanted to get opinions and ideas on techniques to allow this to scale and be as efficient in polling the web site and the mobile sites.

Comment: This probably isn't helpful, but PHP really isn't the best language for this. You may want to consider something else for the real-time components of your applications.

Comment: I must agree with Michael. The best solution here would be to use web sockets.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are better ways. This group of techniques is generally encompassed in what is called [**Comet**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29). What you'll probably want to do is use AJAX long polling. Basically, you use the browser to make a request to the server, and the server doesn't respond until it has new data. Once it has responded, on the browser, you immediately initialize a new request.

Note that an even better way would be to use a web sockets server. Look into those, they are a way to make real-time data transfers between the browser and a server. Lots of people are doing cool things with those in [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) and, for example, [socket.io](http://socket.io/). You do need a dedicated server for this though, not just web hosting.

Comment: Long polls using apache+php will become a big problem. You'll have quite a few open connection at the same time. Resource usage per connection is quite big with apache+php, and apache is, in default configuration, limited to a certain amount of simultaneous connections. Not a very scalable solution, but OK if you don't have to many simultaneous visitors.